# Multiply values from two 2d arrays and put those values into another 2d array

Tags: c++

I am attempting to take a row from a 2d array, and multiply by a column in another 2d array. Then put those values into a third 2d array. The arrays being pulled from are called recipe[][] and prices[][]. The one I'm trying to put the values in is called forecastPrices[][].

Right now I just have:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfProducts ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfProducts ; j++)
    {
        forecastCost[i][j] = someNumber;
    }

}
```

I know that this code only goes through the array and assigns some number to each point. but it's all I have

Comment: *Take a row from a 2d array, and multiply by a column in another 2d array*, would you be more specific about what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all arrays have the same dimensions and type, you can use:

```cpp
for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfProducts ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfProducts ; j++)
    {
        forecastCost[i][j] = recipe[i][j] * prices[j][i];
    }

}
```

Where you loop through rows in `recipe[i][j]` and columns in `prices[j][i]`

Comment: they are not the same size, and I am trying to multiply rows  from one array by columns of another. I have the appropriate values to traverse the other arrays, I am just stumped logically on how to do that.

Comment: You might be thinking of matrix multiplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250188/multiply-two-matrices-in-c I don't think it's possible to just multiply rows by columns if the dimensions are mismatched.